# Updating to 3.1.1 following RailsTutorial.org screencast

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, railstutorial.org

I am following the lesson 13 screencast from Railstutorial.org and am hung up on the error below:

```
Failures:

  1) PagesController GET 'home' when signed in should have the right follower/following counts
     Failure/Error: response.should have_selector('a', :href => following_user_path(@user),
       expected following output to contain a <a href='/users/1/following'>0 following</a> tag:
       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
       <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
       <title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home</title>
       <!--[if lt IE 9]>
         <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
         <![endif]--><link href="/assets/blueprint/screen.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
       <link href="/assets/blueprint/print.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
       <!--[if lt IE 8]><link href="/assets/blueprint/ie.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><![endif]--><link href="/assets/custom.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
       <script src="/assets/defaults.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       </head>
       <body>
         <div class="container">
                <header><a href="/"><img alt="Sample App" class="round" src="/assets/logo.png"></a>
         <nav class="round"><ul>
       <li> <a href="/">Home</a>
       </li>
                <li> <a href="/help">Help</a>
       </li>
                <li> <a href="/signin">Sign in</a>
       </li>
        </ul></nav></header><section class="round"><h1>Home</h1>
       <p>Find me in app/views/pages/home.html.erb</p>


       <a href="/signup" class="signup_button round">Sign up now!</a>



                </section><footer><nav class="round"><ul>
       <li> <a href="/about">About</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="/contact">Contact</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="http://news.railstutorial.org/">News</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">About</a> </li>
                </ul></nav></footer>
       </div>
         </body>
       </html>
     # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:119:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 7.32 seconds
10 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:117 # PagesController GET 'home' when signed in should have the right follower/following counts
```

my gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rack' , '1.3.3'

gem 'rails', '3.1.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'


gem 'gravatar_image_tag', '1.0.0.pre2'
# gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.pre2'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.2'
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.4'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.7.0'
  # gem 'annotate-models', '1.0.4'
  gem 'annotate', '2.4.0'
  gem 'faker', '0.3.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.7.0'
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.0.rc8'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.0'
  # gem 'autotest', '4.4.6'
  # gem 'autotest-rails-pure', '4.1.2'
  # gem 'autotest-fsevent', '0.2.4'
  # gem 'autotest-growl', '0.2.9'
end
```

Wondering possibly if its an rspec version problem? --

pages_controller_spec.rb

```
      it "should have the right follower/following counts" do
                get :home
                response.should have_selector('a', :href => following_user_path(@user),
                                                   :content => "0 following")
                response.should have_selector('a', :href => followers_user_path(@user),
                                                   :content => "1 follower")
      end
```

pages_controller.rb

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController


  def home
    @title = "Home"
    if signed_in?
      @micropost = Micropost.new 
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    end
  end

  def contact
    @title = "Contact"
  end

  def about
    @title = "About"
  end

  def help
    @title = "Help"
  end
end
```

when I comment out the pages_controller_spec.rb section I go green

Any thoughts?

Update 1:

Changing RSPEC versions did not work, tried 2.4.0, 2.6.1 and 2.6.4

Update 2:

Changing to Rails 3.1.0 did not work

Update 3:

Triple Checked running rspec in original sample app Rails 3.0.8 GREEN

update 4:

home page

```
<% if signed_in? %>

    <table class="front" summary="For signed-in users"> 
        <tr>
            <td class="main">
                <h1 class="micropost"> What's up? </h1>
                <%= render 'shared/micropost_form' %>
                <%= render 'shared/feed'%>
            </td>
            <td class="sidebar round">
                <%= render 'shared/user_info' %>
                <%= render 'shared/stats' %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<% else %>


<h1>Home</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/pages/home.html.erb</p>


<%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path, :class => "signup_button round" %>


<% end %>
```

Comment: Did you buy the screencast?

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that when a user visits `/pages/home` they should see a link constructed from the following code:

```
<a href='/users/1/following'>0 following</a>
```

Do you actually see that link when you visit the home page?

If not, then you should add it, I'd imagine there's a section or chapter where the author walks you through doing that.

Comment: hmm i do not have that.. this is my home page shown above in update 4... I kind of jumped ahead of the book 3.1.1 not covered yet... so of course biting off more than i can chew but thats part of the fun... where on the home page should it be added to see if that would solve it